# Cannot instantiate Mapper interface

Tags: automapper, datamapper, objectmapper, mapper

Getting a null pointer because Mapper interface not instantiated for Junit Not sure how to fix. Example code bellow,

@Autowired
private Mapper mapper;

Detail newDetail= mapper.map(detail, Detail.class);

Any help would be awesome

I tried instantiating with other maps and it didn’t work.

Comment: do you have a configuration how to instantiate a Mapper in your regular code? Do you also have that for the tests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I used a @Mock injection and mocked the mapper being called like in the main function. This solved the npe.